# mariadb InterfaceError when inserting into specific table using sqlalchemy

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, mariadb

I have many tables in the DB and I have same generic sqlalchemy code that inserts/updates if entry exists.

Code which does that goes like this:

```
for entry in valid_entries:
    try:
        try:
            insert_stmt = Insert(model).values(entry)
            on_duplicate_key_stmt = insert_stmt.on_duplicate_key_update(entry)
            result = session.execute(on_duplicate_key_stmt)
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(str(e))
            session.rollback()
            continue
        session.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Upsert exception, {entry} not upserted: {e}")
```

Only when inserting into one specific table I sometimes get mariadb.InterfaceError. Entry which fails inserting is not in any way different than the others which succeed. This table is the largest in the DB, it has around 120 columns.

I am using SQLAlchemy 1.4.46, MariaDB 10.9.4, python 3.9.2. One weird thing is that I had this problem before and I solved it by downgrading SQLAlchemy to 1.4.21. I verified this by going down version by version and confirmed that it worked on 1.4.21 and did not on 1.4.22. Then I did not experience that error anymore until recently (now it's happening no matter if it's 1.4.21 or 1.4.22). And always on the same table after it already successfully inserts some entries.

Any ideas?

Edit:

Code which creates creates engine goes like this

```
    conn_str = f"mariadb+mariadbconnector://{db_user}:{db_pwd}@{db_host}:3306/db_name"
    engine = create_engine(conn_str, pool_pre_ping=True)
```

Comment: Which driver do you use to connect to MariaDB server?

Comment: @GeorgRichter not sure how to check this, I guess drivers were already installed of the server where I am running this. I ran dpkg -l | grep libmariadb and got following:

ii  libmariadb-dev                    1:10.9.4+maria~deb10           amd64        MariaDB database development files
ii  libmariadb3:amd64                 1:10.9.4+maria~deb10           amd64        MariaDB database client library

Comment: @kichma somewhere in your code base there must be a `engine = create_engine(<URL>)`, the sheme in this URL tells which driver you're using, maybe [edit] your question to add the URL.

Comment: https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/7457 could be the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing driver was the simplest way to solve my problem. Possibly the same issue as https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/7457 as suggested in comment by Georg Richter.

```
conn_str = f"mysql+pymysql://{db_user}:{db_pwd}@{db_host}:3306/parser"
```